# Run app only in swap

Tags: linux, memory, swap

I've a very low priority level program who consume large of memory. I need to free RAM for other programs. My objective is to `kill -STOP <pid>` this process and ```kill -CONT  when i need it. But RAM consumtion still problematic.

So:

Is it possible to run program only in swap ? If yes how ?

Comment: Add more RAM to your server...?

Comment: Effectively you are asking if you can make a low priority process consume all your I/O. Even if it was possible, it sounds like a silly thing to do.

Comment: My objective is to ```kill -STOP <pid>``` this process and ```kill -CONT <pid>``` when i need it. But RAM consumtion still problematic.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. Things that are swapped out are, by definition, not in memory and not eligible to be executed.

Comment: I read of IBM system I/AS 400 allow to run swapped objects *(I agree it isn't really swapped, since it doesn't make distinction between swap and RAM address space)*.